# javascript forcing multiple http get requests to be synchronous using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a module exporting a function who's goal is to collect all streamed string data from a URL and return the complete result:

```
'use strict'
const http = require("http");
const bl = require("bl");

async function getUrlData (url) {
  http.get(url, (response) => {
    response
      .pipe(bl((err, data) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        
        const stringData = data.toString();
        return stringData
      }));
  });
}

module.exports = getUrlData;
```

I also have a main file which accepts 3 URLs as arguments and attempts to print out the value from getting the data from each URL in the exact order given.

```
'use strict'
const getData = require('./http-collect-module');

const urls = process.argv.slice(2);

const main = async () => {
  urls.forEach((url) => {
    var stringData = await getData(url);
    console.log(stringData)
  });
}

main();
```

I'm trying to make one get complete before moving onto the next, however am receiving this error:

```
    var stringData = await getData(url);
                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I cannot understand why I'm getting this error since the main function is an async one. Any help appreciated

Comment: Yes, `main` is async, but the callback function of `forEach` isn't. And `forEach` also doesn't support async callbacks. If you want to execute one promise after the other use a simple `for ..in` or `for .. of ` lop

Comment: ah that was it  thanks! now getting undefined in each console.log but it's progress at least!

Comment: Your `getUrlData` function doesn't return anything ...